# mysql get free time set set meeting

Tags: mysql, sql, time

Ι have a table in MySQL with

```
     date  starttime    endtime 
11/2/2014   10:00:00   10:45:00
11/2/2014   10:45:00   11:15:00
11/2/2014   11:45:00   12:15:00
11/2/2014   12:15:00   13:30:00
```

I need the sql query to give back to me the time that I can set a new meeting for 30 min

Comment: You mean for instance insert a new row with these information:
`11/2/2014 11:15:00 11:45:00` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_time = array();

$query = "SELECT starttime, endtime FROM table";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//fetch result
while ($array_time[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {}

/*
$array_time = Array (
  ...
  1 => array('starttime' => 10:45:00, 'endtime' => 11:15:00)
  2 => array('starttime' => 11:45:00, 'endtime' => 12:15:00)
  ...
)
*/

//array of free time for your meeting
$free_time = array();

foreach($array_time as $i => $row){
  if($i > 0) {
    //if this is not the first time row

    //get this row starttime
    $this_starttime = strtotime($row['starttime']);

    //and the last endtime
    $prev_endtime = strtotime($array_time[$i-1]['endtime']);

    //get the difference
    $diff = $this_starttime - $prev_endtime;

    //if difference is more or equal than 30 minutes
    if($diff >= strtotime('30 minutes')) {
      $free_time[] = array('starttime' => $row['starttime'], $array_time[$i-1]['endtime']);
    }
  }
}
```

I think you can't do this in MySQL query, so PHP could help you.
Hope it works, I have not tested it out.

**But try to save your data by other way, this is not so effective, as you can see.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer.In my example i need the it to give me back 11:15:00 because the only meeting after is at 11:45 and i can set a 30 min meeting at this time between 11:15:00 till 11:45:00

Comment: the_ousek THANK YOU! i'm waiting

Comment: @rafiamar if I helped, please accept my answer. thanks too!